# Holding the previous state of a select field after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML for with a select field - drop down list. When a user makes a mistake and goes back there the data selected by the user is lost and show the original message. Is there a way of holding this state, so I don't get the user to select this every time he or she makes a mistake. Thanks.
**Hi people when you fill a form in Safari and submit to a preview page, when you click back it takes you to the original form and still shows the selected item against  asking you yo select anything fresh, for some reasons what soever, Firefox does not do this, it there a way to make it do this, so that one can have a uniform experience on different platform**

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this post. 
This is your question
[How to remember last state with Jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2527370/how-to-remember-last-state-with-jquery)

Comment: thanks but this is not exactly what i want. I have a select list and i want the last selected option to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

This [article sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95655/comparison-of-ways-to-maintain-state) it up pretty well.

You can also use `window.name` to stash string data. Put some sort of token and your selected index in there and check for a value in window.name on page load.